# Putting a CVS file into an NSArray to graph with core-plot libararies

Tags: xcode, excel, csv, nsarray, core-plot

I am trying to take a simple excel csv file with x and y values and put it into an NSArray so that I can use it to graph a scatter plot using core-plot.  I have already set up code to display a graph with certain data plots here:

**JACViewController.m**

```
#import "JACViewController.h"
@implementation JACViewController
@synthesize scatterPlot;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-10, 100)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8, 50)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6, 20)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-4, 10)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-2, 5)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 4)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 16)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6, 36)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(8, 64)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 100)]];

self.scatterPlot = [[JACSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:data];
[self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
}

@end
```

But now I want to use a CSV file from excel and display the data that I get from there.

The Excel file looks like this:

a1= "Data X" b1= "Data Y" a2:a8=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) b2:b8=(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is exported as UTF8 text. Pass a URL to the CSV document into this call.

You can use

`NSString *exceldata = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:aurl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

to get the data then split the string into lines with

`NSArray *lines = [exceldata componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];`

finally each line can be split into components with

```
NSMutableArray *plotdata = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *line in lines)
{
NSArray *points = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
CGFloat xpoint = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
CGFloat ypoint = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

[plotdata addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint,ypoint)]];
}
```

This ignores that line 0 is a header and that an empty or malformed line will crash the routine but shows the basic code of what you need to do.